# How do I solve this import error from keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'RMSprop' from 'keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py)

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `tensorflow.keras` instead of vanilla `keras`, as even `keras` official documentation is using `tensorflow.keras` now. ([RMSprop](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/rmsprop/))

That is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```